# how to capture the length of a list or objectives in a list

Tags: r, list

how can get the length of a list(or obs?) for my list "my_data" . It looks like this:

[image]
the sample list can be build using

```
list(pk24_1.CSV = c("pk24_1.CSV", "pk24_2.CSV", "pk4.CSV", "pk6_1.CSV", 
"pk6_2.CSV", "pk6_3.CSV", "pkc.CSV", "pkc1.CSV"), pk24_2.CSV = c("pk24_1.CSV", 
"pk24_2.CSV", "pk4.CSV", "pk6_1.CSV", "pk6_2.CSV", "pk6_3.CSV", 
"pkc.CSV", "pkc1.CSV"), pk4.CSV = c("pk24_1.CSV", "pk24_2.CSV", 
"pk4.CSV", "pk6_1.CSV", "pk6_2.CSV", "pk6_3.CSV", "pkc.CSV", 
"pkc1.CSV"), pk6_1.CSV = c("pk24_1.CSV", "pk24_2.CSV", "pk4.CSV", 
"pk6_1.CSV", "pk6_2.CSV", "pk6_3.CSV", "pkc.CSV", "pkc1.CSV"), 
    pk6_2.CSV = c("pk24_1.CSV", "pk24_2.CSV", "pk4.CSV", "pk6_1.CSV", 
    "pk6_2.CSV", "pk6_3.CSV", "pkc.CSV", "pkc1.CSV"), pk6_3.CSV = c("pk24_1.CSV", 
    "pk24_2.CSV", "pk4.CSV", "pk6_1.CSV", "pk6_2.CSV", "pk6_3.CSV", 
    "pkc.CSV", "pkc1.CSV"), pkc.CSV = c("pk24_1.CSV", "pk24_2.CSV", 
    "pk4.CSV", "pk6_1.CSV", "pk6_2.CSV", "pk6_3.CSV", "pkc.CSV", 
    "pkc1.CSV"), cy1.CSV = c("cy1.CSV", "cy24.CSV", "cy6.CSV"
    ), cy24.CSV = c("cy1.CSV", "cy24.CSV", "cy6.CSV"), cy6.CSV = c("cy1.CSV", 
    "cy24.CSV", "cy6.CSV"), chem_1.CSV = c("chem.CSV", "chem_1.CSV"
    ), coag.CSV = c("coag.CSV", "coag1.CSV"), cont.CSV = c("cont.CSV", 
    "cont_1.CSV"), cont_1.CSV = c("cont.CSV", "cont_1.CSV"), 
    dov.CSV = c("dov.CSV", "dov_1.CSV"))
```

I tried many ways and could not get it work. Could someone guide me on this.

I have tried

```
lst5<- lapply(my_data,
        function(x) data.frame(Obs = length(x[[1]])
      ))
```

```
lst5<- lapply(my_data,
        function(x) data.frame(Obs = nrow(x))
      ))
```

```
lst5<- lapply(my_data,
        function(x) data.frame(Obs = length(x)
      ))
```

I want to get sth that looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
lst5 = data.frame(Data = names(my_data), obs = lengths(my_data))
```

Comment: The results look like what I want but with row name that is the same as "data". I am new to R. as my_data is a list, should I use the command that can go through the list one by one?  i am always struggle how to deal with list.

Comment: @Stataq You can pass the argument `row.names = NULL` to get rid of the row names. Row names are a left-over from an old style of data analysis. Nowadays, the general consensus is never to use row names.

Comment: Thanks so much! Is it a way to use `lapply(my_data, function(x) , ...` to get the same results? why `lst5<- lapply(my_data,  function(x) data.frame(Obs = lengths(x)
      )) ` could not work?

Comment: @Stataq Kind of: `lengths(lst)` is essentially the same as `unlist(lapply(lst, length))`. But your attempt to create the data.frame *inside* the `lapply` doesn’t really work — to make it work you’d have to write fairly convoluted code: `do.call('rbind.data.frame', lapply(my_data, function (x) data.frame(Obs = length(x)))`.